# ContentView - Binding Context is set to null

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding, maui, xamarin.forms.collectionview

Currently I am playing around with .Net Maui but I maybe it's the same behavior as Xamarin.

I've created a simple Search-Control which is based on a `ContentView`.

**ObjectSearchControl.xaml**

```
    <ContentView
        x:Class="DeepBlue.Controls.ObjectSearchControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:DeepBlue.Converter"
        xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:DeepBlue.Helpers"
    x:Name="MySearchControl">
    <StackLayout
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <SearchBar
                x:Name="ObjectSearchBar"
                IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
                Keyboard="Text"
                Placeholder="{Binding SearchBarPlaceholderText}"
                TextChanged="ObjectSearchBar_TextChanged" />

        <CollectionView
                x:Name="ObjectResultView"
                HeightRequest="500"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"
                SelectionChanged="ObjectResultView_SelectionChanged">
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**ObjectSearchControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
    public partial class ObjectSearchControl : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty SearchBarPlaceholderTextProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SearchBarPlaceholderText), typeof(string),
            typeof(ObjectSearchControl), string.Empty);

    public static readonly BindableProperty DataSourceProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DataSource), typeof(object),
            typeof(ObjectSearchControl));


    public ObjectSearchControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Content.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public string SearchBarPlaceholderText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(SearchBarPlaceholderTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(SearchBarPlaceholderTextProperty, value);
    }


        public object DataSource
        {
            get => (object)GetValue(DataSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

This `ContentView` I've inserted in my Page

```
            <StackLayout
                x:Name="SelectFishingSection"
                HeightRequest="600"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <controls:ObjectSearchControl
                    DataSource="{Binding NonFilterdDataSource}"
                    HeightRequest="550"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    SearchBarPlaceholderText="Placeholder"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
```

After running the code the control rendered and the Placeholdertext in the `SearchBar` is set correct. So I thought the implementation of the binding is correct. But in my `CollectionView` no element is rendered.

So I debugged a lot and found out that the `BindingContext` is set 2 times. When I initialize the control all the properties have got NULL values. -> seems okay

Then the control is appearing and I get the elements from DB and set them to "DataSource".

```
    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <mctBehaviors:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding SetDataSourcesCommand}" EventName="Appearing" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>
```

```
    private async Task SetDataSources()
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            NonFilterdDataSource = new ObservableCollection<MyTestModel>(await DataService.GetAll());
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

That's also called and seems correct. After that `BindingContext` is set (`OnBindingContextChanged` is called in my ObjectSearchControl.xaml.cs) and all properties (SearchBarPlaceholderText and DataSource) have got correct values. At this point in DataSource there are 9 Elements!

If I continue debugging the DataSource is set to NULL and also the `BindingContext` is set to NULL! But I don't understand why?
Output window in VS shows only "External Code" and I can not figure out why this is happening.

I found a few similar questions but none of the could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

After analysing the "External Code" in VS I found out that the source of the problem must be somewhere in the measurement for the control. So I removed                     `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` from my `controls:ObjectSearchControl` implemention and after that the problem was gone. BindingContext is set only one time and everything is working as expected!

Comment: Interestingly, this is the second bug recently involving `VerticalOptions="...AndExpand"`. (The previous bug was button command not getting fired; as if an element extended too far vertically, blocking the button.) Something is wrong re layout of those options. Specific to Maui; not seen in Xamarin Forms.